# Sorting an array with two sorted sequences in alternate position in linear time and constant space

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

This was asked to me today in an interview and was kicked out after staring at the question for 5 min.

> Given an array *A* such that the subsequence of all the odd positions ([*A*<sub>1</sub>, *A*<sub>3</sub>, *A*<sub>5</sub>, …]) and the subsequence of all the even positions ([*A*<sub>2</sub>, *A*<sub>4</sub>, *A*<sub>6</sub>, …]) are each in sorted order — e.g. [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5] or [3, 8, 4, 11, 5] or [5, 2, 7, 4] — sort *A* in O(*n*) time and O(1) space (including stack space and output array space).

I have racked my brain and picked my friend's over it for the last two hours. Google did not yield any answers. I do not want to color any opinions but I feel like this might not be possible to solve in the given complexities.

How can we solve this? All inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a trick question? I think the best you can do is O(n log n). It was explained to me once in an algorithm MOOC, though I cannot recall the reasoning behind it.

Comment: O( n log n) is the minimum you can achieve.

Comment: Found it, sorting based on comparisons cannot be faster than O(n log n): https://hackernoon.com/is-it-possible-to-sort-an-array-faster-than-o-n-log-n-time-a053b942c5fe

Comment: Does O(1) assume inplace sorting?

Comment: Is it not possible to skip some comparisons as we know that alternate elements are sorted?had this question not been O(1) space, this is an easy sorted merge. Now the question is if that is possible in constant space. 
@MBo That was not exactly clarified. Extra space should not depend on the size of the array.

Comment: You can easily sort in linear time if result is in new array. Auxiliary memory is O(1) in this case.

Comment: In that case space complexity is O(n), isn't it? Let's assume total space as O(1).

Comment: Is there a constraint on the range of values? If so counting sort might be a solution.

Comment: OK, so sorting should be inplace.

Comment: Count sort requires extra space no matter what. So radix and count are not useful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (1) the two interleaved sequences can form one monotonic sequence when un-interleaved, *and* either (a) the array starts with the lowest number and is of odd length, or (b) the array starts with the lowest number of the second sequence (the one that will be the right side when un-interleaved) and is of even length, we may be able to reverse the algorithm decribed in [*A Simple In-Place Algorithm for In-Shuffle* (Peiyush Jain, 2008)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1598).

We would have to perform the "cycle leader" sequences first, followed by the cycle shifts.

Example 1

```
[1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 10, 5]
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9
 1  6  2  7  3  8  4   9  5

|1| unaffected

   |1     3                |
   m = 4; 2m = 3^2 - 1
   cycles start on 3^0, 3^1
   (4 swaps with 7 and the other
    numbers form a longer cycle.)
```

Example 2 (simple):

```
[1, 5, 2, 7, 3]
 1  2  3  4  5
 1  4  2  5  3

|1| unaffected

   |          |
   m = 1
   cycle in 2m => 2, 5
   cycle in 2m => 3, 7
   cycle shift by m between 5 and 3
   => 2, 3, 5, 7
```

I wouldn't expect anyone to come up with this in an interview without being allowed to research, though :)

Comment: This seems cool but I don't seem to get it into my head. Would a pseudo code be possible?

Comment: @AntarikshaYelkawar sorry, I just noticed your comment now. I'm, it seems like it would be a little complicated to code. Is there something about the algorithm in the article or my suggestion that I could help you understand better?